# Float bug in chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-float

I'm getting a really strange bug in chrome and Safari only. I have a section with 3 divs inside. I want them to be put side by side, so I put a float left on the first one, a display inline-block on the middle one and a float right on the last one. This gives me exactly what I want. The problem is that if I resize the browser in chrome and Safari, my responsive work the first time but when I resize the browser again to its original size, the third div doesn't display correctly! Even weirder, if I don't even resize the browser and I just uncheck the float attribute in the inspecteur and then I recheck it after, it doesn't go back to its original position! I heard about a bug in chrome, but I'm not sure if I'm talking about the same bug...

Here is my css and html:

```
<section>
    <div>
        <img src="img/engrenage.png" alt="logique" />
        <h2>LOGIQUE</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/coueur.png" alt="passionne" />
        <h2>PASSIONNÉ</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/montagne.png" alt="perseverant" />
        <h2>PERSÉVERANT</h2>
    </div>
</section>

/* line 41, ../sass/accueil.scss */
article section {
  margin: 15px auto 30px;
  width: 96%;
}
/* line 47, ../sass/accueil.scss */
article section div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f4f5f5;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  width: 32%;
}
/* line 55, ../sass/accueil.scss */
article section div:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}
/* line 62, ../sass/accueil.scss */
article section div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* line 69, ../sass/accueil.scss */
article section div:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
}
```

Here is the link to the page:
Kevinduguay.ca/en

Comment: Apparently, there is some JavaScript code that executes and rearrange the divs. If i disable JavaScript, they don't display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you set you 3 divs to inline-block instead of float? Make sure there are no spaces between the divs (else the browser will display spaces).

```
article section div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
article section div:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 5%;
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Then, for responsive display, just use media-queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must to "float: left" the 3 divs.
And you must to put a div with a "clear: both" after.
Obviously you need to set a margin to separate those divs.

```
<section>
    <div>
        <img alt="LOGIC" src="/bundles/public/img/engrenage.png">
        <h2>LOGIC</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img alt="PASSIONATE" src="/bundles/public/img/coueur.png">
        <h2>PASSIONATE</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img alt="PERSEVERING" src="/bundles/public/img/montagne.png">
        <h2>PERSEVERING</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use display:flex. Remove all display inline-block and floats. Set the article section to flex, and on media query change the flex-direction parameter.

```
article section {
  width: 96%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
   flex-direction: column;
}
```